# Propel: need Criteria for the following SQL query

Tags: sql, criteria, inner-join, propel

After half a day of headaches trying to figure out a double INNER JOIN, I finally got it right:

```
SELECT product.id as product_id, count(purchase_vaucher.object_id) as purchased 
FROM purchase_vaucher 
INNER JOIN purchase on purchase.id = purchase_vaucher.object_id 
INNER JOIN product on purchase.product_id = product.id 
WHERE purchase.is_paid=1 
GROUP BY product.id 
ORDER BY purchased_amount desc;
```

What is this about: basically, three tables: `product`, `purchase`, `purchase_vaucher` (yeah I know it's "voucher", but I didn't invent the schema). Basically, `purchase` contains purchases made and a back-link to a `product`. `purchase_vaucher` contains info about vouchers and a back-link to a `purchase`. What I needed from this query: For all `purchase`s who have `is_paid=1`, count all vouchers of all the purchases with the same product id and group them by the product id.

What I need is: the above query translated as a Propel `Criteria` API calls.

I am starting to work on this right away, but I will be happy if I could save some time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiously enough, it turned out to be very easy:

```
$purchased_amount_column = 'purchased_amount';

$c = new Criteria();
self::addSelectColumns($c);
$c->addAsColumn($purchased_amount_column, 'COUNT(' . PurchaseVaucherPeer::OBJECT_ID . ')');
$c->addGroupByColumn(ProductPeer::ID);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn($purchased_amount_column);
$c->add(PurchasePeer::IS_PAID, 1, Criteria::EQUAL);
$c->addJoin(PurchasePeer::ID, PurchaseVaucherPeer::OBJECT_ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(PurchasePeer::PRODUCT_ID, ProductPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
```

Had a trouble with the pager, but it took me 5 mins to realize that the way to make it count the records of such non-trivial Criteria was simply this:

```
$pager->setPeerCountMethod('customCount');
...
// customCount:
return YourPeer::doCount($yourCriteria);
```

That was it really.